# Connection from Play Framework to Docker container

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, docker

In an EC2 Amazon Linux instance(based on Centos) I am running RabbitMQ in a docker container and I have configured it to listen to 5672 and 15672 tcp ports on 0.0.0.0. This container process is running under root.

When I am testing to see if there is a process running on that port:

```
nc -z 127.0.0.1 5672
```

I get the correct ouput.

However, when I am trying to run Play Framework under the ec2-user, Akka hangs and times out when it tries to connect to 127.0.0.1:5672

If I am running Play Framework under root, everything works.

Do I need to add any firewall rules to allow processes running under ec2-user to connect to processing running under root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you shouldn't have to. It sounds like you have a different problem, possibly permissions in your play framework distribution.  You can try something like:

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /whatever/dir/where/play/is
```

also check as `ec2-user`, not as `root`:

```
nc -z 127.0.0.1 5672
```